# Problems with MariaDB output

Tags: php, sql, left-join, mariadb, inner-join

I'm trying to create a menu based in MariaDB tables.
We have a associative table, which connects with other tables

```
#ass_products_categories
product_id | category_id
-------------------------
1          | 1    <- GENDER
1          | 3    <- AGE
1          | 16   <- TYPE
2          | 2
2          | 3
2          | 16
3          | 2
3          | 4
3          | 17
4          | 1
4          | 2
4          | 3
4          | 16
```

The columns references to products table and categories table, obviously

```
#products
id | name          | qty | is_published
---------------------------------------
1  | T-Shirt Black | 10  | 1
2  | Long Dress    | 0   | 1
3  | T-Shirt Blue  | 10  | 0
4  | T-Shirt Red   | 10  | 1

#categories
id | name        | tipology_id
------------------------------
1  | Man         | 1 <- GENDER
2  | Woman       | 1 
3  | 3 a 5 years | 2 <- AGE
4  | 6 a 7 years | 2
16 | T-Shirt     | 4 <- TYPE
17 | Dress       | 4
```

This is the output I expect.

```
[Man]
---- [3 A 5 years]
--------- T-Shirt

[Woman]
---- [6 a 7 years]
--------- T-Shirt
--------- Dress
```

I can do it with PHP and a lot of loops, but I know is possible to make this with only a good query. But I'm really stuck in a lot of left joins and inner joins.

The point is that: if there's nor a single product published in a category or all products in that category are qty = 0, the category should not appear in menu. The nearest approach I've found was WITH, but it's not possible/available in MariaDB (at least not in the host MariaDB server)

Sorry my bad english, please.
Thanks for helping.

Comment: Consider handling data display related requirements in application code (eg: PHP).

Comment: you don't have any information about hierarchy into database so you have to create it via PHP or review your tables structures but you'll still need PHP

Comment: Why `Man -> 3A5years -> T-Shirt` instead of `T-Shirt -> 3A5years -> Man`? There's no information in your table about the **level** of a category. They all look at the same level. Don't they? It seems your database modeling is incomplete.

Comment: Yes... I can do it handling in PHP. But that mean some querys inside loops and this is a bad approach. I was wondering the possibility of make that with only a one good query.

Comment: What version of MySQL? 5.x or 8.x? It seems it's 5.x.

Comment: Hey @TheImpaler sadly theres no information. But the current menu organization is with this order GENDER > AGE > CATEGORY TYPE because is a kid store and the marketing consider this the order of importance for customer choices

Comment: @TheImpaler 10.1.34-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.18.04.1

Comment: If you had MariaDB 10.2, a recursive CTE would produce the result you want. Since it's not the case, you'll probably need to get the raw data and re-assemble it in your PHP application.

Comment: According to your data, output is different for `Women`

Comment: Thks. I will change it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very complex operation but just for join query idea. [Check here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ea4ae3/27)

```
SELECT DISTINCT gender.name, 
                age.name, 
                type.name 
FROM   ass_products_categories a 
       JOIN products p
         ON p.id = a.product_id and is_published = 1
       JOIN (SELECT c.name, 
                    product_id 
             FROM   ass_products_categories pc 
                    JOIN categories c 
                      ON c.id = pc.category_id 
                         AND c.tipology_id = 1) gender 
         ON gender. product_id = a.product_id 
       JOIN (SELECT c.name, 
                    product_id 
             FROM   ass_products_categories pc 
                    JOIN categories c 
                      ON c.id = pc.category_id 
                         AND c.tipology_id = 2) age 
         ON age.product_id = a.product_id 
       JOIN (SELECT c.name, 
                    product_id 
             FROM   ass_products_categories pc 
                    JOIN categories c 
                      ON c.id = pc.category_id 
                         AND c.tipology_id = 4) type 
         ON type.product_id = a.product_id
```

Comment: This is most near I have found. Thank you. I will need another query to check if the products are published / disponibles or is better to extends a bit more this query to make it in one time?

Comment: You can add inner join with products to do that and check my updated code

Comment: Is that! Thank you too much. I would never get a solution for that alone.